# Fetching Data from Json Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-native

I can't fetch Data from this Json Data: https://flow.simpas.ai/paysagiste/article?userid=w8&businessid=ecofence_wattel_set_1_25m&companynumber=0899607494

I'm Getting No Error but I can't see the Data that am trying to Fetch

### The Problem is the response of API is an object and Flatlist receives an array. So by What should I replace the Flatlist?

***This is The Code:***

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  SafeAreaView,
  Keyboard,
  ScrollView,
  Alert,
  FlatList
} from 'react-native';

import COLORS from '../src/conts/colors';
import Button from '../src/views/components/Button';
import Input from '../src/views/components/Input';
import Loader from '../src/views/components/Loader';

const EditScreen = (item) => {

  const [data,setData] = useState([])
  const [loading,setLoading]= useState(true)


  const fetchData = ()=>{
     fetch("https://flow.simpas.ai/paysagiste/article?userid=w8&businessid=ecofence_wattel_set_1_25m&companynumber=0899607494")
     .then(res=>res.json())
     .then((json)=>setData(json))
     .catch((error)=>console.error(error))
     .finally(()=>setLoading(false))
     }
  useEffect(()=>{
       fetchData()
  },[])

  const {businessid,link,title} = item

  const [inputs, setInputs] = React.useState({
    businessid: '',
    link: '',
    title: '',
  });
  const [errors, setErrors] = React.useState({});
  React.useState(false);


  const RenderCollection = (item) =>{

      return(

        <View style={{marginVertical: 20}}>

          <Input
            onChangeText={text => handleOnchange(text, 'businessid')}
            label="businessid"
            defaultValue={item.businessid}
          />


          <Input
            onChangeText={text => handleOnchange(text, 'link')}
            label="link"
            defaultValue={item.link}
          />

          <Input
            onChangeText={text => handleOnchange(text, 'title')}
            label="Title"
            defaultValue={item.Title}
          />


          <Button title="Save"  />
          <Button title="Cancel"  />

        </View>
      )
    }



  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Loader visible={loading} />
      <ScrollView>
        <Text> Edit  </Text>
        <Text>  Now You Can Edit ! </Text>

        <FlatList
                    data={data}
                    renderItem={({item})=>{
                      return RenderCollection(item)
                    }}
                    keyExtractor={item=>item.businessid}
                    onRefresh={()=>fetchData()}
                    refreshing={loading}
                    />
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default EditScreen;
```

The output should be a pre-filled form
But that What am getting:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2Etn.png)

Comment: is this really react-native - or is it c++?

Comment: Did you debug, are you sure the response worked properly? Is anything visible in the console? Did you see the network request go out, does the response contain the expected data?

Comment: Yes React Native

Comment: I try to debug the app using the console and I see the Json Data:**{"author":"Ecofence","avatar":"","title":"3 Wattels Set 1","cover":"https://www.mybelgo.be:8444/isiweb/download/documentDownload.jsf?document=45&key=99256f5e47a9d156b66bf6b834976bd8","pagetype":"article","addtext":"Ajouter","businessid":"ecofence_wattel_set_1_25m","link":"https://flow.simpas.ai/pay.......}]}**

Comment: visible Json Data is the same in the link that am trying to fetch from

Comment: You can make an array of 1 item `<FlatList data={[data]} ... />` but I doubt this is what you actually want. So the question roots to either 1. why doesn't your API return an array in the first place. or 2. If the API is correct, why do you want to render 1 item using a FlatList - If you want to render 1 item, you can replace the entire `<FlatList ... />` with just `{RenderCollection(data)}`

Comment: Okay I'm following you I replace `<FlatList ... />` with just `{RenderCollection(data)}`

Comment: So how can I access data  ?

Comment: because using for example `{item.businessid}` not working

Comment: Notice My API is not an array you can check it here: https://flow.simpas.ai/paysagiste/article?userid=w8&businessid=ecofence_wattel_set_1_25m&companynumber=0899607494

Answer (score 0):

You are not seeing because the response of API is an object and Flatlist receives an array. I advice you to remove Flatlist for this case.

Comment: What should I do instead of the FlatList ?

Comment: Fell free to use react-native components, like View and Text to customize

Comment: I try Both **Text** and **View** instead of Flastlist  but I Errors